# Помогите со структурой Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, структуры

Не могу понять как вывести содержимое.

К примеру, есть контроллер:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }  

        public function index()
        {           
            // код
        }

        public function view($slug = NULL)
        {
            // код
        }

        public function photo()
        {
            // код
        }
}
```

При вызове:

сайт/news - открываются все новости

сайт/news/view/2 - открывается 1 новость с id 2

Как добавить к одной новости конечную ссылку photo, чтобы открывалась страница с фотографиями данной новости, к примеру:

сайт/news/view/2 - открывается 1 новость с id 2

сайт/news/view/2/photo - открывается страница фотографий к новости с id 2

Не могу понять как реализовать. Если в контроллере указывать функцию photo, то она и открывается как сайт/news/photo.

Можно ли как-то сделать вариант с сайт/news/view/2/photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать можно через роуты, см. http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/general/routing.html

Правило будет примерно таким: `$route['news/view/(\d+)/photo'] = "news/photo/$1";`

метод в классе соответственно такой:

```
public function photo($id=0)
{
    // код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает